# Декодирование из cp1251 в utf-8

Tags: python

Есть переменная с текстом в кодировке cp1251, который мне надо перекодировать в utf8.
В теории код должен иметь такой вид:

```
Text = Text.decode('cp1251')
Text = Text.encode('utf-8')
```

Как это уже понятно, этот код не работает.
Как мне выполнить все эти действия, написав максимально читаемый и сжатый код?

Comment: Что именно значит "не работает"?

Comment: Действия decode должны быть в типе bytes, в который перевести без изменений кодировки я не могу

Comment: А encode должен быть в типе str. По крайней мере, мне так ошибки твердят

Comment: Приведите Ваши ошибки и содержание переменной Text

Comment: А заодно объясните откуда текст в переменной берётся.

Comment: Я пишу сайт на cgi, использую поле <input>, через которую передаю кириллицу. Браузер перекодирует в "%E9%F6%F3%EA%E5%ED", а при попытке вывести этот текст через обычный str, выводится ошибка кодировки

Comment: А мне нужен текст полностью на кириллице

Comment: Если `Text = b'\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'` то всё замечательно работает. Вопрос непонятен

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял из комментариев, у Вас есть некоторый текст, который кодировался в cp1251, а после в URL.

Пример для его декодирования:

```
import urllib.parse


t = 'йцукен'
w = urllib.parse.quote(t.encode('cp1251'))               # %E9%F6%F3%EA%E5%ED

res = urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(w).decode('cp1251')  # 'йцукен'
```

***Кодирование:***

Переменная `t` содержит текст "йцукен"

1. С помощью `encode` кодируем её в "cp1251"
2. С помощью `quote` кодируем в URL

Получается пример, который Вы приводили в комментариях ("%E9%F6%F3%EA%E5%ED")

***Декодирование:***

1. С помощью `unquote_to_bytes` декодируем из URL
2. С помощью `decode` декодируем из "cp1251"

В итоге переменная `res` содержит "йцукен".

**UPD:**
[image: Интерпретатор]
Как видите, всё отлично работает. Консоль прямо с [python.org](https://www.python.org)

Comment: При попытке использовать четвертую строку кода выводит "пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ"(без третьей, т.к. результат должен быть декодирован)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код. Я не могу сказать, что Вы делаете не так, просто по выводу. По крайней мере, мой код работает. Переменная `w` хранит Ваш пример, после выполнения последней инструкции, переменная `res` хранит искомое значение "йцукен"

Comment: line 22, in <module>\r\n    w = urllib.parse.quote(Text.encode(\'cp1251\'))  \r\n  File "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\encodings\\cp1251.py", line 12, in encode\r\n    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)\r\nUnicodeEncodeError: \'charmap\' codec can\'t encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>\r\n'

Comment: Извиняюсь, что так скомкано, ищу способ передать код нормально

Comment: @vyatcheslav Извините, действительно ничего не видно. Внесите правку в свой вопрос. Чтобы добавить код, оберните его в ```

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/r1PeJR5RV

Comment: @vyatcheslav Код по ссылке не воспроизводит проблему, ошибка уже совсем другая - `Text = None`