# Python CGI, ???, английский

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb
print("""
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
""")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
Bla = form.getvalue('Bla')
print(Bla)
```

Стэковерфлоу, я написал этот код на Python. Он должен выводить просто значение, которое я вписываю на предыдущей странице

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb
print("""
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
""")
print("""<form action="Second.py">""")
print("""<textarea name="Bla"
rows="5" cols="102"
placeholder = "Текс"></textarea>""")
print("""<input type="submit" value="Подтвердить />""")
print("</form>")
```

А вместо банального ААА, получаю: [image: ???]

Я перепробовал на разных языках, такая проблема видна везде, кроме английского(поправка: везде с символами не из английского алфавита)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за того, что браузер кодирует русские символы в "cp1251", а после в URL.
Вам нужно правильно раскодировать пришедшее значение:

```py
import urllib
...

...
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
Bla = form.getvalue('Bla')
Bla = urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(Bla).decode('cp1251')
...
```

Более подробно я недавно описал это [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991042/339283).